# How to grab table data from dinamic web page by Python and Selenium (or other way)

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

Could smbdy help. How can I grab table from this web page using python and selenium?
https://abit.lunn.ru/lists/772#1 and put it to pandas dataframe.

There is an ability in this page to save xlsx file on harddrive. There will be good to automatically save this excel file on disk by selenium (or other way), after that I can use it in dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

I have no experience to work with web parsing instruments, especially dinamic web pages with javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.